# Xamarin droid project fails to build after installing Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, appcompatactivity

My xamarin droid project fails with lots of error after updating to xamarin.Android.Support.V7.AppCompact

To get the custome tool bar in my droid project with mvvmcross I wrote the below code which cased and issue

```
  public class MantraasView : MvxAppCompatActivity<Core.ViewModels.MantraasViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MantraasView);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

then I tried to install appcompact v7 which failed saying target version is 6,
then I changed my target version and updated those packages and installed 
mvvmcross.droid.support.v4
mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.Appcompact and from then I am getting the following errors.

> error: OnAdapterChangeListener is not public in ViewPager; cannot be
>   accessed from outside package
>         android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener   Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\ViewPager_OnAdapterChangeListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>         android.support.v4.app.SharedElementCallback.OnSharedElementsReadyListener
>   symbol:   class OnSharedElementsReadyListener   location: class
>   SharedElementCallback Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\app\SharedElementCallback_OnSharedElementsReadyListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>         android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat.OnQueryTextListener
>   symbol:   class OnQueryTextListener   location: class
>   SearchViewCompat  Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\widget\SearchViewCompat_OnQueryTextListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>         android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat.OnCloseListener   symbol:
>   class OnCloseListener   location: class
>   SearchViewCompat  Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\widget\SearchViewCompat_OnCloseListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>         android.support.v7.widget.MenuItemHoverListener   symbol:   class
>   MenuItemHoverListener   location: package
>   android.support.v7.widget Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\MenuItemHoverListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: package android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater does not
>   exist
>         android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener   Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\AsyncLayoutInflater_OnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>   android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat.AccessibilityStateChangeListener
>   symbol:   class AccessibilityStateChangeListener   location: class
>   AccessibilityManagerCompat    Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>   android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat.TouchExplorationStateChangeListener
>   symbol:   class TouchExplorationStateChangeListener   location: class
>   AccessibilityManagerCompat    Japam.Droid D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.java

Comment: Have you deleted bin and obj folders and tried to do a clean rebuiild? :)

Comment: Haven't deleted the folders but cleaned the build, will try deleting now

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Thank you it worked.

Comment: I had a similar error message, this was the first result in google so I am leaving this here for others who might have the same problem. I had longer project root path, and because of that my equivalent of:

D:\sourcecode\Japam\Japam.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java

was over 260 characters long, more than the windows path length limit